# forEach() in React JSX does not output any HTML

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a object that I want to output via React:

```
question = {
    text: "Is this a good question?",
    answers: [
       "Yes",
       "No",
       "I don't know"
    ]
}
```

and my react component (cut down),  is another component

```
class QuestionSet extends Component {
render(){ 
    <div className="container">
       <h1>{this.props.question.text}</h1>
       {this.props.question.answers.forEach(answer => {     
           console.log("Entered");  //This does ifre                       
           <Answer answer={answer} />   //THIS DOES NOT WORK 
        })}
}

export default QuestionSet;
```

as you can see from the snippit above, i'm trying to insert an array of the component Answer by using the array Answers in props, it does itterate but is not outputted into HTML.

Answer (score 408, accepted):

You need to pass an array of element to `jsx`. The problem is that **`forEach` does not return anything (i.e it returns `undefined`)**. So it's better to use `map` because `map` returns an array:

```
class QuestionSet extends Component {
render(){ 
    <div className="container">
       <h1>{this.props.question.text}</h1>
       {this.props.question.answers.map((answer, i) => {     
           console.log("Entered");                 
           // Return the element. Also pass key     
           return (<Answer key={answer} answer={answer} />) 
        })}
}

export default QuestionSet;
```

Comment: Use var i as key is not a good choice in some situation for virtual dom.

Comment: @maquannene Indeed thanks for pointing that out. Here's a good post on why https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: FWIW you can also pass in other kinds of collections. You just need to unroll them so they'll work with `.map()`. e.g. `Object.keys(collection).map(key => ...` and assign a variable for conveniently working with `collection[key]`