# Reactjs select box fail to append option value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{this.props.datacat.forEach(function (key,value) {

  Object.keys(key).forEach(function(key2,value2) {
       console.log("yes");
       if(key2 == 'name'){
           return <Option value="zzz" key="bbb">fff</Option>;

       }
   })
})}
```

//data of this.props.datacat

```
[
  {
    "4967": "Others.",
    "4968": "Sports & Beachwear > Others.",
    "4969": "Lingerie & Nightwear > Others.",
    "4971": "Pants & Shorts > Others.",
    "name": "Women Clothes"
  },
  {
    "4798": "Supplements > Others.",
    "4802": "Men's Grooming > Others.",
    "4952": "Others.",
    "4953": "Medical Supplies > Others.",
    "4954": "Personal Pleasure > Others.",
    "4955": "Personal Care > Others.",
    "4956": "Pedicure & Manicure > Others.",
    "6647": "Lips > Lip Tint"
    "name": "Health & Beauty"
  }
]
```

I'm beginner of reactjs, I have some data and want to loop through it and render to select box value. In the above code I tried to loop the data and render to select box option value. It successfully prints yes in console log but the html does not render as expected. Anyone has faced such an issue before? Please help :(.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMOlh.png)

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySwRN.png)

Comment: Please provide us the data in the object `this.props.datacat`, in json.

Comment: @catch me share your json code

Comment: `forEach` returns undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React foreach in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616355/react-foreach-in-jsx)

Comment: provided the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly use `map` to render items,
Second, you will also need to return whatever returns from the object as well, as it's a double loop that we need to traverse through.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "4967": "Others.",
    "4968": "Sports & Beachwear > Others.",
    "4969": "Lingerie & Nightwear > Others.",
    "4971": "Pants & Shorts > Others.",
    name: "Women Clothes"
  },
  {
    "4798": "Supplements > Others.",
    "4802": "Men's Grooming > Others.",
    "4952": "Others.",
    "4953": "Medical Supplies > Others.",
    "4954": "Personal Pleasure > Others.",
    "4955": "Personal Care > Others.",
    "4956": "Pedicure & Manicure > Others.",
    "6647": "Lips > Lip Tint",
    name: "Health & Beauty"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return data.map(singleData=>{
     return Object.keys(singleData).map(key=>{
       if(key==='name'){
         return <div>{singleData[key]}</div>
       }
     })
    })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

***forEach*** method only loops over items. i urge you to try ***.map*** array helper method.

To make this work with .forEach, create empty array and push in your Option component.

then return your empty array