# Dynamically create buttons in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a checkbox dynamically according to the data in API and then call the function inside my `render` function.

Can anyone suggest me any way, as I had used `forEach` but the data seem do not passed and hence I'm getting an error: `forEach is undefined`.

My snippet:

```
sizel=()=> this.state.data.sizes.forEach(function(size){
    <CheckBox
     title={size}
   checked=''
   />
 })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React foreach in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616355/react-foreach-in-jsx)

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax, please, am new to react native, I would be obliged if you help.

Comment: No still am getting undefined

Comment: what is the value of data.sizes ?

Comment: I think the problem in you code it that you use .forEach which doesn't return your checkbox just change it to .map as @JosephD. does in his answer instead

Comment: "sizes": ["38", " 39", " 40", " 41", " 42", " 43", " 44", " 45", " 46"]  it differs for every product, like for shoes they are numbers, for chlothes they are like XL,L,S etc @AshwithSaldanha

Answer (score 0):

check `data.sizes` has length also should not be undefined.

add this:

```js
const { sizes } = this.state.data;
if( sizes && sizes.length){
 this.state.data.sizes.map(size => <CheckBox title={size} checked=''/> )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a validation before invoking forEach method, just like this:

```
   sizel = () => this.state.data && this.state.data.sizes && this.state.data.sizes.forEach(function (size) {
    return (
      <CheckBox
        title={size}
        checked=''
      />
    )
  })
```