# only first array element is rendering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array but only first array element is rendering.How to do this. This is response from Firebase. In console it is fine but in jsx only first element is rendering.
Here is my code

```
let users=[
           {
            email: "rabina@gmail.com",
            id: "jqGZhhXDa8xI4iMtYO0U",
            joined_at: Fri Dec 03 2021 03:44:44 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time),
             name: "Rabina chandak",
            profile: "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur=2"
        },
         {
        id: 'LVEy69S3VIZXdztSKTyG',
         name: 'Jeevan',
         email: 'jeevan@gmail.com',
         joined_at: Fri Nov 12 2021 11:33:33 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time), 
        profile: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur=5'
        }
        ]



  users.map((user)=>{
    console.log(user.id)
    })



 const User=()=>{
   return(        
     div className="flex">
    <div className="bg-gray-100  w-full p-4 justify-between">
    <div className="lg:mx-16 mx-8">
    <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-1 gap-4">
    {

        {users.forEach((user)=>{
            return <UserCard key={user.id} name={user.name} email={user.email} id={user.id} profile={user.profile} session={session}/>
        })}
    }
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     )
    }
```

Comment: you're returning an object in User Function. Remove the curly braces after `return`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The current code in your question isn't valid (unbalanced tags, invalid syntax in the objects, etc).

Comment: @Jeevan, please format your code. it's hard to read

Comment: Just wait  I will give my whole code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [forEach() in React JSX does not output any HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616355/foreach-in-react-jsx-does-not-output-any-html)

Comment: Now nothing is returning...

Comment: First  whole array element render then again  only first one is render and others is...

Comment: I had used useEffect hooks.After removing it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
               <div>
                {users.map((user) => (
                  <h2>{user.name}</h2>
                ))}
              </div>
```

instead of this, it will work perfect:

```
 const User = () => {
    return users.map(user => {
        return (
            <p>
                {user.id}
            </p>
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: Not work, I hove done in same way in my real code...

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what the problem was and why your new code fixes it. That will make it more helpful to the op.

Comment: Only first array element is rendering but not others

Comment: Returning an array of nodes is valid React, there's no need to wrap the whole thing with a `<div>`.

Comment: First entire element is rendering then only first element is rendering and other is not rendering...